# Polymer 1.0 is there a way to easily pass all default parameters to a template element

Tags: design-patterns, data-binding, attributes, polymer, polymer-1.0

I want to pass all attributes to 1 or more new elements of a native HTML element.

```
<dom-module id="clear-filter-button">
    <template>
        <button type="button" id$=[[id]] class$=[[class]]....></button>
    </template>
 </dom-module>
```

I want to do this but without having to add all the attributes one by one.  I know you can simply extend an element, but that doesn't help if I wan't to something more involved, like surround the button with a div or setup default values.

A more concrete example:  I want to create a custom button that will have a built in function (foo) when the button is clicked and a default value for the text on the button.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, binding each property one by one is the way to achieve what you want to achieve.